# What should i write on onchange for second dropdown

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, asp-classic

I have problem for second dropdown. My first dropdown work well but for my second dropdown i cant reload and hold the value like my first dropdown.

This is my first dropdown

```
<select name="line" id="selLine" onchange="myLine(this.form)">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="DD2" <% if "DD2"=request("line") then response.write " selected" %>>DD2</option>
                        <option value="DD8" <% if "DD8"=request("line") then response.write " selected" %>>DD8</option>
                    </select>
```

This is my second dropdown

```
<select name="package" id="Package" onchange="myPackage(this.form)">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Package 1" <% if "Package 1"=request("package") then response.write " selected" %>>Package 1</option>
                        <option value="Package 2" <% if "Package 2"=request("package") then response.write " selected" %>>Package 2</option>
                    </select>
```

and this is my js

```
<SCRIPT>
function myLine(form){
var val=form.line.value;
window.location="f1.asp?line=" + val ;
}
function myPackage(form){
var val2=form.package.value;
window.location="f1.asp?line=" + val + "+package=" + val2;
}
</script>
```

hope someone can help me, I found many jquery for this kind of problem but as I am new in this language I don't know where to use jquery, can someone show me simple example to use jquery in asp classic, thank you

Comment: `val` is out of scope in your `myPackage` function, as it's only declared within `myLine()`. You either need to make `val` a global variable, or call `myPackage()` from **within** `myLine()`.

Comment: i change my val into global variable, but when i select value form second drop down, my first drop down value change to undefined, can i know why? @ObsidianAge

Comment: Querystring values are seperated by `&`, not `+`.    `window.location="f1.asp?line=" + val + "&package=" + val2;`

Comment: thank you so much now i know @SearchAndResQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to declare val outside of the functions to get around this.

```
<SCRIPT>
var val = null;
function myLine(form){
  val = form.line.value;
  window.location="f1.asp?line=" + val ;
}
function myPackage(form){\
  if(val == null) return;
  var val2 = form.package.value;
  window.location="f1.asp?line=" + val + "&package=" + val2;
}
</script>
```

Comment: when i select second dropwdown, my first dropdown value will become null :(

Comment: Oh, I didnt notice but u used + for query string instead of &. See my edited answer.

Comment: thanks for the help, hope this will help other beginner too :)